# CSV to BQ: empty fields instead of null values

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that is loading a CSV file from GCS into BQ. The details are here: [Import CSV file from GCS to BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105669/import-csv-file-from-gcs-to-bigquery).

I'm splitting the CSV in a ParDo into a TableRow where some of the fields are empty.

```
String inputLine = c.element();

String[] split = inputLine.split(',');

TableRow output = new TableRow();
output.set("Event_Time", split[0]);
output.set("Name", split[1]);
...
c.output(output);
```

My question is, how can I have the empty fields show up as a null in BigQuery?  Currently they are coming through as empty fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's turning up in BigQuery as an empty String because when you use `split()`, it will return an empty String for `,,` and not `null` in the Array.

Two options:

1. Check for empty String in your result array and don't set the field in `output`.
2. Check for empty String in your result array and explicitly set `null` for the field in `output`.

Either way will result in `null` for BigQuery.

**Note**: be careful splitting Strings in Java like this this. `split()` will remove leading and trailing empties. Use `split("," -1)` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values).

**BTW**: unless you're doing some complex/advanced transformations in Dataflow, you don't have to use a pipeline to load in your CSV files. You could just [load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_csv_files) it or read it [directly from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage).

Comment: Thanks Graham, I am building towards a pipeline with transformations but starting very simple. Appreciate your answer and additional feedback.